# If statement always returns true when testing if value is in a range

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I wrote this code:

```
if (10 < prompt("Enter a number from 10 to 30") < 30) {
    alert("Ok");
}
```

The problem is it always returns `true` (if I enter any number). Could anybody explain why?

Comment: numbers aren't strings and vice-versa.

Comment: why write code like this??????

Comment: Perhaps you've entered an alternate universe where all numbers are between 10 and 30?

Comment: @TMcKeown: Actually, I could see why someone with a mathematical background might write something like this. It's common to specify bounded ranges something like this: (10 <= *x* < 30), which means *x*, where *x* is >= 10 and *x* is < 30. Perhaps nicael is a math major?

Comment: maybe but it's a simple piece of logic that is being turned into something unnecessarily overly complicated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because it is parsed as

```
(10 < prompt(...)) < 30
```

since `(10 < prompt(...))` is a boolean expression that converts to 0 or 1 in a numeric context, this is either

```
0 < 30
```

or

```
1 < 30
```

both of which are true.

Answer (score 5):

In javascript there aren't `a < b < c` comparisons. You must use `a < b && b < c`:

```
var num = prompt("Enter a number from 10 to 30");
if(10<num && num<30) alert("Ok");
```

Comment: There *are* `a < b < c` comparisons because everything can be interpreted as numbers. They just don't do what OP expected, or what they do in other languages like Python

Comment: @NiklasB. Yeah, I meant comparisons in a mathematical way.

Answer (score 4):

This is not the right way to test if a variable is between two values.

```
10<prompt("Enter a number from 10 to 30")<30
```

Parses as

```
(10 < prompt("Enter a number from 10 to 30")) < 30
```

The problem is that that first bit, `(10 < ...)`, will return either `true` or `false`. However, both when comparing Booleans to integers, `true` is coerced to `1`, and `false` is coerced to `0`. So in the next part of the statement `0 < 30` and `1 < 30` will both return `true`.

Try this:

```
var value = prompt("Enter a number from 10 to 30");
if(value > 10 && value < 30) { alert("Ok"); }
```